# How to write a recursive macro_rule go catch the slice inside the slice

Tags: rust, macros

I am trying to write a macro_rules that can expand slice to generate some struct.

The simple example I am writing is:

```rust
macro_rules! test {
    (&[$($arg:expr),*]) => {
        &[$(test!($arg)),*].to_vec();
    };
    ($arg:expr) => {
        let a = $arg; // this no sense line just for this test case
    };
}
```

What I expect is:

`test!(&[&1, 2, 3, &[4, 5]]);` will expand to

```rust
&[let a = &1, let a = 2, let a = 3, &[let a = &4, let a = &5].to_vec()].to_vec();
```

but it keeps giving me the

```rust
&[let a = &1, let a = 2, let a = 3, let a = &[4, 5]].to_vec()
```

Do I make some mistakes in this recursive macro? How can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that once you captured the fragment as `expr`, it cannot be decomposed again. As explained in the reference:

> #### [Forwarding a matched fragment](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#forwarding-a-matched-fragment)
>
> When forwarding a matched fragment to another macro-by-example, matchers in the second macro will see an opaque AST of the fragment type. The second macro can't use literal tokens to match the fragments in the matcher, only a fragment specifier of the same type. The `ident`, `lifetime`, and `tt` fragment types are an exception, and can be matched by literal tokens. The following illustrates this restriction:
>
> ```rust
> macro_rules! foo {
>     ($l:expr) => { bar!($l); }
> // ERROR:               ^^ no rules expected this token in macro call
> }
>
> macro_rules! bar {
>     (3) => {}
> }
>
> foo!(3);
> ```
>
> The following illustrates how tokens can be directly matched after matching a `tt` fragment:
>
> ```rust
> // compiles OK
> macro_rules! foo {
>     ($l:tt) => { bar!($l); }
> }
>
> macro_rules! bar {
>     (3) => {}
> }
>
> foo!(3);
> ```

The only solutions are to use a proc macro, or use a [TT muncher](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/patterns/tt-muncher.html) and do the (very complex) parsing of `expr` yourself.